# ROS/catkin compiled C++ file won't find image sources

Tags: c++, ros, allegro5, catkin

I created a C++ game that uses images from a folder in the same parent directory.

```
/game_folder
----/Images
--------icon1.png
--------icon2.png
----game.cpp
```

Program uses Allegro 5 library to include images:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* icon1 = al_load_bitmap("Images/icon1.png");
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* icon2 = al_load_bitmap("Images/icon2.png");
```

And this works great.

However now I need to place this program into ROS/catkin package 'beginner_tutorials'. If I place both `Images` folder and `game.cpp` into `../catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials` it compiles fine using *catkin make*, but I get `Segmentation Fault` during runtime.

```
/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials
----/Images
--------icon1.png
--------icon2.png
----game.cpp
```

I used gdb and guess the error is caused by the program not finding the Images folder.

I also tried to place the Images folder to `../catkin_ws/devel/include/beginner_tutorials` (the same place where header files are included)

```
/catkin_ws
----/devel/include/beginner_tutorials
--------/Images
------------icon1.png
------------icon2.png
----/src/beginner_tutorials
--------game.cpp
```

and changed code accordingly:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* icon1 = al_load_bitmap("beginner_tutorials/Images/icon1.png");
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* icon2 = al_load_bitmap("beginner_tutorials/Images/icon2.png");
```

But this didn't work.
Where am I supposed to place the Image folder for it to be successfully included in the code? Do I also need to make adjustments in the CMakeLists.txt?

**-EDIT**
Tried something with CMakeLists.txt with no success:

```
set(game_SOURCES
  src/game.cpp
  src/Images/
)

add_executable(game ${game_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(game ${allegro_LIBS})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this does not work is that your code gets **compiled** and is then placed inside the **`catkin_ws/devel/lib/<package_name>` folder** (`lib` not `include`!). Then when you launch the code it will look only in paths relative to the executable. This means you would actually have to place it inside the `catkin_ws/devel/lib/<package_name>` folder. The problem with that is though that as soon as you clean the workspace all of these directories will be deleted and you would have to re-copy all the files to it after each `catkin clean`.

For this purpose the ROS **C++** API has though functions that allow you to browse the folder of a given package inside the `catkin_ws/src` folder or display all available packages when [including the header file `ros/package.h`](https://wiki.ros.org/Packages#C.2B-.2B-):

```
#include <ros/package.h>

// ...

std::string const package_path = ros::package::getPath("beginner_tutorials");
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* icon1 = al_load_bitmap(package_path + "/Images/icon1.png");
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* icon2 = al_load_bitmap(package_path + "/Images/icon2.png");
```

should do the trick. This will make the code look in `catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials` path.

Similarly in **Python** the syntax would be:

```
import os
import rospkg

# ...

rospack = rospkg.RosPack()
package_path = rospack.get_path('beginner_tutorials')
icon1_path = os.path.join(package_path, "Images", "icon1.png")
icon2_path = os.path.join(package_path, "Images", "icon2.png")
```

Comment: "undefined reference to `ros::package::getPath(..". I added 'roslib' to CMakeLists.txt lines: find_package(..here..) and generate_package(..here..) and also to package.xml   <build_depend>roslib</build_depend>
  <exec_depend>roslib</exec_depend>. Didn't work.

Comment: @AntsAus Have you added `roscpp` as well as `roslib`? Additionally I have added it to `catkin_package (CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp ...)` as well as `target_link_librararies(${catkin_LIBRARIES} ...)`.

Comment: `undefined reference ...` generally indicates a linker error. So probably you are not linking to the `roslib` library. Potentially your order in the `CMakeLists.txt` is wrong. It should be `catkin_package(...)`, `include_directories(...)`, `add_executable` and `target_link_libraries(...)`.

Comment: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lroslib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lroscpp
When I tried to add them to target_link_libraries(game ${allegro_LIBS} roslib roscpp)

Comment: @AntsAus Try to write `target_link_librararies(${catkin_LIBRARIES} ...)` instead else it will think you want to link it to external libraries.

Comment: @AntsAus Can you clone another package that contains `ros::package::getPath` such as [this minimal example](https://github.com/nikolausmayer/cmake-templates/tree/master/generic-ros-catkin-cplusplus-launchfiles-cmake-example), try if it compiles fine and compare its `CMakeLists.txt` with yours?

Comment: This worked: target_link_libraries(game ${allegro_LIBS} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

Comment: @AntsAus Excellent, glad to hear that! Sorry, should have been more clear, of course you have to mention your executable as well!