# Roslaunch cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, ros, catkin

I'm having problems with opening a shared library when using `roslaunch`.

I have a ROS package with a c++ script containing the line:

```
handle = dlopen("./rk4.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

This shared library resides inside my ROS package. I managed to build the package with catking build, having in my CMakeLists.txt the lines

```
add_library(RK4 SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(RK4 PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/SharedLibs/rk4.so)

target_link_libraries(simulator_node
  RK4
  ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS}
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} 
)
```

The problem is when I try to run my executable. Since the library is not in a folder where libraries usually are, I added the path to that folder to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and exported it.
However I don't understand why I don't get the error in the title only when I use `rosrun` while I'm inside the exact folder in which the library is.
My issue is that I want to launch that node with a launch file, but using `roslaunch` I get the error in the title anyway, even if I run it from inside the folder of that library.

Comment: Couldn't you just add [`ros::package::getPath("your_package_name")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802827/9938686) to the directory in `dlopen`?

Comment: @2b-t what do you mean with it? Could you explain it more explicitly? 
(Sorry, I'm a beginner)

Comment: What I meant is that `dlopen` takes as a first argument the `filename`. With `ros::package::getPackage("your_package_name")` you can get the directory of your package. If your ROS package resides inside your package directory as you stated then you should be able to combine it to an absolute file path like `handle = dlopen(ros::package::getPackage("your_package_name") +  "/rk4.so", RTLD_LAZY);`. I am not sure if that solves your issue as I haven't had the opportunity to test it yet.

Comment: Just tested it and it works if you take into consideration the conversion from `std::string` to a `char const*` (see my answer below). **I would not recommend you modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`  as it is an environment variable. Instead try to keep your modifications as portable as possible.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most portable way of doing so is to **supply `dlopen` with the full path to the shared library file by using `ros::package::getPath("your_package_name")`** as follows (and not modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`!). This way you can easily get your package up and running on another computer!

- Modify your node to **load the shared library using the absolute path to the shared library by using the function `ros::package::getPath` from the `ros/package.h`** header:

  ```
  std::string const library_path = ros::package::getPath("your_package") + "/relative/path/to/libyourlib.so";
  auto* handle = ::dlopen(library_path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);
  ```

  This for example would be a minimal working example for a node `your_node` :

  ```
  #include <cstdlib>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

  #include <dlfcn.h>

  #include <ros/ros.h>
  #include <ros/package.h>

  int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "your_node");
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    std::string const package_path = ros::package::getPath("your_package");
    std::string const library_path = package_path + "/src/libyourlib.so";
    auto* handle = ::dlopen(library_path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {
      std::cerr << "Error: could not load shared library!" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Library successfully loaded!" << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
  }
  ```
- Modify your **`CMakeLists.txt` to include the `roslib` library** which contains the `ros::package::getPath` function:

  ```
  find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    roscpp
    roslib
  )

  include_directories(
    ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  )

  add_executable(your_node src/your_node.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(your_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

> `handle = dlopen("./rk4.so", RTLD_LAZY);`

will succeed *if and only if* there is `rk4.so` in the current directory. In particular, it will *ignore* any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` setting.

This is working as designed.

If you want `dlopen` to respect `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, change it like so:

```
  handle = dlopen("rk4.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

A better approach is to make above change *and* avoid the need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` by using `-Wl,-rpath=/dir/where/rk4.so/is/installed` at link time of the application.